# Help with script to make a directory, change directory, download a file, then back out of that directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, directory

All,

I'm trying to write a script that will create a folder, go into that folder, create another folder, go into that folder, download files, back out of that folder, create a new folder, go into that folder, download files, back out of that folder, back out of the folder again to I'm returned to the root of the folder I started from. This then would repeat again; I feel like if I can get the first iteration correct then it'll be easy to just copy/paste to run over and over again as needed.

Here's what I have (and isn't 100% working):

```
#Main Folder 1
mkdir 'XXX'
cd 'XXX'
##Sub Folder 1
mkdir 'YYY'
cd 'YYY'
(Download File command here - working properly in testing)
cd ..
##Sub Folder 2
mkdir 'ZZZ'
cd 'ZZZ'
(Download File command here - working properly in testing)
cd ..
cd ..
```

The issues I'm facing are this:

1. When the script creates the folder it has (what looks like) a • at the end of the folder name
2. The script doesn't change the directory "up" one level and then again two levels

I've searched and not found anything about the first issue. It seems that "cd .." won't work in a script (as it throws the error " cd: can't cd to .." and there's something else I should use but pinning down what that is has been difficult.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might find `pushd` and `popd` useful here.

Comment: `mkdir -p "XXX"/"YYY" && cd "XXX"/"YYY"` is shorter and easier to read. Don't use ' though.

Comment: Both the unexpected trailing character on the directory name and the failure of `cd ..` suggest a problem with your script's line endings - how are you creating the script, exactly?

Comment: @PRATAP XXX/YYY/Files - XXX/ZZZ/Files (and on and on) is what I'm looking for. Then I would do the same again to make CCC/YYY/Files - CCC/ZZZ/Files.

Comment: @Rinzwind Would this prevent the "dot" symbol from being created at the end of the folder names? I can certainly make this work if it will do that.

Comment: @steeldriver I'm creating it by hand from scratch? I'm "ok" with writing batch files for DOS and "crappy" at best with Powershell scripts. I figured some of what I know would translate over to linux (and it has) but some things are just different *enough* that it doesn't 100% translate.

Comment: I really meant *what application or editor are you using*? are you sure it is configured to use Unix line endings (`LF`) rather than DOS (`CRLF`)?

Comment: @LinuxNoob87 nope. I would suggest this has something to do with what steeldriver suggests: line endings. Are you doing this from windows or with windows settings?

Comment: @Steeldriver: Notepad in windows.

Comment: @Rinzwind Notepad in windows

Comment: Here is a raw paste from windows of the folder that's created: "YYY"

I've edited the script in nano on the ubuntu machine and do not see any odd/off/out of place characters in the folder name.

Comment: @steeldriver Which program am I going to "Edit -> EOL Conversion"? I've checked nano as well as notepad on windows and dont see "EOL Conversion" in either program. 
Thanks for the assistance. :-)

Comment: @LinuxNoob87 apologies I had a brainfart and read your previous comment as `notepad++`. I don't think `notepad` has such a feature. You can install `dos2unix` on Ubuntu and use that to correct the script's line endings (or use `sed -i 's/\r$//' yourscript`)

Comment: @steeldriver Installed Notepad++ (surprised this VM didn't have it installed already); went to "Edit -> EOL Conversion" and changed it to "Unix LF". This has solved both issues. THANK YOU!

Comment: @LinuxNoob87 nice one :)

Answer (score 1):

A very simple example that will help you is :

```
# OPTION 1
CURDIR=$( pwd )

# OPTION 2
CURDIR=$PWD

D1="XXXXXX"
D2="YYYYYY"

mkdir $D1
cd $D1

mkdir "foo_bar" 
cd "foo_bar"

cd $CURDIR

mkdir $D2
```

3 things to know about this :

1.a) `pwd` is a command to display the current name of current folder

1.b) `$(`....`)` is a way to capture the output of command and transform into a string

1.c)  `CURDIR` is a arbitrary name i choose

2. `$PWD` is a variable usually populated  with the current dir

Comment: It should be noted that if the shell is bash, it attempts to maintain pwd in the variable `$PWD`, so you could use this directly.

Comment: So my idea is to take this, use it as a "template", plug in the correct data, and then run it multiple times. If I used the above script would I need to increase the variable numbers each time? It's doable, but at that rate it would be faster for me to manually download each one as I'd have yet another field to modify for each download.

Comment: For any future readers; this issue was solved above by @steeldriver --- TL;DR - Used Notepad++ to change the "end of line" formatting to Unix based instead of windows based.